# Relationship between $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, correlation

$\Omega_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0.8 & -0.8\\
0.8 & 1 & \rho_1\\
-0.8 & \rho_1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ and 
$\Omega_2=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0.4 & -0.4\\
0.4 & 1 & \rho_2\\
-0.4 & \rho_2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$
are 2 correlation matrices.

Using Sylvester's criterion, I got:   $-1 \leq \rho_1 \leq -0.28$ and $-1 \leq \rho_2 \leq 0.68$

However, when I look at these correlation matrices, I feel that they have sort of relationship, hence, same for $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$.

> Is it wrong to say: $\rho_1=2\,\rho_2?$
>
> Any intuition about it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is wrong. $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are correlation matrixes for any $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ from the intervals that you wrote. If we are not informed what triples of r.v. have this correlation matrixes and how this triples are related, one cannot provide further conclusions.